# Http callback is never called, Vue Laravel

Tags: http, laravel-5, vue.js

Got this in a Vue component (Users.vue). The fetchUsers-function is called but the callback-function is NEVER called. I've tried to attach .error()-func but I get an error of `this.$http.get(...).error is not a function`.

```
<template>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Användare</div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="user in users">
                        <td>{{ id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ email }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        name: "Users",

        ready() {
            console.log('Component ready.')

            this.fetchUsers();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchUsers: function() {
                console.log("Fetching users...");

                this.$http.get('/api/user', (data) => {
                    this.$set("users", data);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I use Laravel's framework that ships with Vue.js. Don't know how it all works but I get the component showing up in the web browser and I get output in the console from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to add vue-resources, try adding

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/0.9.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
this.$http.get('/api/user', (data) => {
    this.$set("users", data);
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error)//check errors
});
```

---

or try this

```
this.$http.get('/api/user').then((data) => {
    this.$set("users", data);
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error)//check errors
});
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I believe the vue-resource is already included through package.json and mixed into the application with elixir's webpack. Otherwise I think it would've complain about the get-method itself

Comment: I found the problem thanx to that error (back end problem). Thank you!